# Unit testing function with Firestore implementation

Tags: android, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

Can someone guide/help me how to write unit test for the getProfileDetails() function:

I have gone through various answers on Stackoverflow but unable to solve this

Here is the relevant code

```
    class EditProfileViewModel(private val mFireStore: FirebaseFirestore,
                               private val mStorageReference: StorageReference) {

    fun getProfileDetails() {
    mFireStore.collection(Constants.USER).document("document_id")
                .get()
                .addOnSuccessListener {documentSnapshot ->
    if (documentSnapshot != null){
    val userProfile = documentSnapshot.toObject(UserProfile::class.java)
    Log.d("TAG","UserProfile ${userProfile.toString()}")
    }
    }.addOnFailureListener { ex ->

                    Log.d("TAG",ex.message.toString())
                }
    }

    }
```

I am able to mock firestore instance using mockito, but not able to figure a way to test code on onSuccess and onFailure.
    Let me know if any other detail is required.